# How do I display an external site in my rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe

I'm trying to build a view in my Rails app that mirrors a page on an external site. So basically, instead of linking to the external page, that external page will be shown in my view already.

Is there a way to do this without using iFrame or is that the only way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Javascript to load the content from an external site, and show it in your view.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
    $("#externalSiteContent").load("http://www.example.com/index.html");
</script>
<div id="externalSiteContent"></div>
```

Comment: If you think the answer works for you, and is best among others, you can accept it.

Comment: so this works for some sites, but the majority of sites, I'm running into a CORs problem: I get this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load "external website". No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

This is an all-rails approach:

```
class YahooController < ApplicationController

  layout false

  def show 
    url = URI.parse('http://www.yahoo.com/')
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
    res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
      http.request(req)
    }

    @body = res.body
  end

end
```

In the view

```
# views/yahoo/show.html.haml
= @body.html_safe
```

Of course, you'll need a route to this.

```
# routes.rb
get '/yahoo', :to => 'yahoo#show'
```

Comment: doing it this way doesn't seem to load the external site's assets

Comment: They are relative, you'd need to update relative urls.